# Dynamic array using perl code. Begineer

Tags: perl, for-loop

I have a PERL code and i wanted to know if i can assign the names of the array dynamically. For eg, here is the code.

```
my @a0=();
my @a2=();
my @a2=();
my @a3=();
my @a4=(); 
my @a5=();
my @a6=();
my @a7=();
```

USing a for loop, can we assign these names dynamically rather than initializing like the one above. Pls let me know....

I tried this but it didnt work.

```
for (my $c=0; $c<= 7; $c++) 
     {
      my @a.$c=();
     }
```

Comment: If you're using 'dynamic names' at any point, what you want is a hash.

Comment: @Sobrique- can you show me one example of that ?

Comment: `my %hash_of_arrays; @{$hash_of_arrays{"a1"}} = ( "some value" ); ` - similar approach works with array of arrays. What you definitely _shouldn't_ do is use symbolic names for a variable - that way lies madness.